# Why is the test runner missing the plugin?

Tags: javascript, testing, npm

I'm working with [Test Runner](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/overview/) for some tests and trying to get the [sendKeys](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/commands/#send-keys) function to work.

Here is my test (the same code from the site):

```
import { sendKeys } from '@web/test-runner-commands';

it('Sample test from test-runner', async () => {
  const input1 = document.createElement('input');
  const input2 = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.append(input1, input2);
  input1.focus();
  expect(document.activeElement).to.equal(input1);

  await sendKeys({
    press: 'Tab',
  });

  expect(document.activeElement).to.equal(input2);
  input1.remove();
  input2.remove();
});
```

The error I keep receiving:

```
Error: Error while executing command send-keys with payload {"press":"Tab"}: Unknown command send-keys. Did you install a plugin to handle this command?
```

I've tried all of the setups to make this work (`@web/test-runner-chrome`, `-puppeteer` and `-playwright`).

Here is my `web-test-runner.config.mjs`:

```
import { esbuildPlugin } from '@web/dev-server-esbuild';
import { chromeLauncher } from '@web/test-runner';

export default {
    browsers: [chromeLauncher({ launchOptions: { args: ['--no-sandbox'] } })],
    coverage: true,
    nodeResolve: true,
    plugins: [esbuildPlugin({ ts: true })], // required for TS support
};
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Just needed to upgrade `"@web/test-runner": "^0.13.1"` to `"@web/test-runner": "^0.13.5"`.